Exclude itself referencing into multimodule maven project
I have this pom.xml for multi-module project:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.alopatin.kafka_learning.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>resources</module>
        <module>producer-simple</module>
        <module>producer-json</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>23</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>23</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.alopatin.kafka_learning.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        ...
    </build>
</project>

Sub-module resources contains common resources for all sub-modules. I don't need any dependencies in this sub-module.
How can I prevent adding dependencies from root pom.xml into one sub-module resources?
Now, I get error:

The project com.github.alopatin.kafka_learning.java:resources:1.0
(D:\Wokrspace\kafka-learing\java\resources\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]
'dependencies.dependency.[com.github.alopatin.kafka_learning.java:resources:1.0]'
for com.github.alopatin.kafka_learning.java:resources:1.0 is
referencing itself. @
com.github.alopatin.kafka_learning.java:java:1.0, D:\Wo
krspace\kafka-learing\java\pom.xml, line 36, column 21


Why have you defined a dependency onto that module in your parent? Those dependencies are inherited to each sub module... only define the dep where it's really needed...

@khmarbaise Dependency resources will be used in all sub-modules. And instead of adding it in all sub-modules I'd like to add it only in parent pom.xml but exclude from resources itself. I thought it will be great add in one place :-)

dont parenting to parent.pom in your submodule pom
